How to read Avro files in Pyspark?
How to read Avro files in Pyspark on Jupyter Notebook ?!
Avro is built-in but external data source module since Spark 2.4. Please deploy the application as per the deployment section of "Apache Avro Data Source Guide".
I tried the following
! spark-submit --packages com.databricks:spark-avro_2.11-4.0.0.jar

APPROACH 1
df = spark.read.format("com.databricks.spark.avro").load("xxx.avro")
APPROACH 2
df= spark.read.format("avro").load("xxx.avro")
APPROACH 3
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark import SparkConf, SparkContext
    
spark = SparkSession.builder \
            .appName('DataFrame') \
            .master('local[*]')\
            .config('spark.jars', 'spark-avro_2.11-4.0.0.jar') \
            .getOrCreate()
df = spark.read.format('avro').load(file)

Throwing error:
AnalysisException:  Failed to find data source: avro. Avro is built-in but external data source module since Spark 2.4. Please deploy the application as per the deployment section of "Apache Avro Data Source Guide". 

   


This should do the work, based on this documentation.
Add org.apache.spark:spark-avro_2.12:3.5.1 to the spark submit:
./bin/spark-submit --packages org.apache.spark:spark-avro_2.12:3.5.1

To load/save data in Avro format, you need to specify the data source option format as avro(or org.apache.spark.sql.avro).
df = spark.read.format("avro").load("examples/src/main/resources/users.avro")
df.select("name", "favorite_color").write.format("avro").save("namesAndFavColors.avro")


Still throwing the same error.

@EMKAY Could you please provide more details of your environment? Are you using a standalone spark application, a cluster, or is it in a Databricks environment?
